# Interchanging summations and integrals over disjoint sets

Tags: probability, measure-theory, solution-verification

Recently I came across a particular conundrum. Below I'll state it fully:

- Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, $\{ A_n \}_{n = 1}^\infty \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ be a sequence of disjoint sets and let $X$ be a $\mathcal{F}$ - measurable function s.t. $X \in \mathcal{L}^1$, *i.e.* $X$ is integrable.

**Question**: Can we use the dominated convergence theorem to show that the equality below,

\begin{equation*}
\int_{\cup_{n = 1}^\infty A_n} \; X \; dP = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_{A_n} \; X \; dP,
\end{equation*}

holds?

I actually concocted a proof which I'm unsure of its correctedness and would really like some input. To that effect, let me state the dominated convergence theorem (DCT) from Athreya's "Measure Theory and Probability Theory" (pg. 57):

> **(Dominated Convergence Theorem)**: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $f_n, g: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ - measurable functions. If $| f_n |  \leq g \;$ a.e. - $P$ for all $n \geq 1$, $\int g \, dP < \infty$ and $f_n \rightarrow f \;$ a.e. - $P$, then $f \in \mathcal{L}^1$,
>
> \begin{equation*}
> \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int \, f_n \; d P = \int \, f \; dP
> \end{equation*}

Now, under the conditions prior to my question, my goal is to use the DCT to prove qthe equality. Let us start by defining $f_n$ and $g$:

\begin{equation*}
f_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n X \cdot \mathbb{1}_{A_i} \quad \text{and} \quad g = |X|.
\end{equation*}

The inequality required by the DCT holds, since

\begin{equation*}
|f_n| = \left| \sum_{i = 1}^n X \cdot 1_{A_i} \right| \leq \sum_{i = 1}^n |X \cdot 1_{A_i}| = \sum_{i = 1}^n |X| \cdot 1_{A_i} = |X| \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^n 1_{A_i} \leq |X| = g.
\end{equation*}

Because $X \in \mathcal{L}^1$, we know that $\int g \; dP = \int |X| \; dP < \infty$. Also, our sequence of functions $f_n$ converges to $f = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty X \cdot 1_{A_i}$, that is,

\begin{equation*}
f_n \rightarrow f.
\end{equation*}

These three facts guarantee that all criteria in the DCT is meet, so it must be that

\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \int X \cdot 1_{A_i} \; dP & = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^n \int X \cdot 1_{A_i} \; dP\\[3pt]
& = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int \sum_{i = 1}^n X \cdot 1_{A_i} \; dP\\[3pt]
& = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n \; dP \\[3pt]
& = \int f \; dP \\[3pt]
& = \int \sum_{i = 1}^\infty X \cdot 1_{A_i}
\end{align}

where the second and fourth equalities hold by linearity and by the DCT respectively.

Now, to conclude, we show that the equality we set out to prove actually holds:

\begin{equation*}
\int_{\cup_{n = 1}^\infty A_n} \; X \; dP = \int \; X \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^\infty 1_{A_i} \; dP = \int \sum_{i = 1}^\infty X \cdot 1_{A_i} = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \int X \cdot 1_{A_i} \; dP.
\end{equation*}

My main concern is that I made a mistake somewhere in the proof so any comments are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct! Another approach is based on splitting $X = X^+ - X^-$, where $X^+,X^-$ are the positive and negative parts of $X$ to reduce matters to showing
$$
\int_{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n} X = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{A_n}X
$$
when $X$ is a nonnegative random variable. In this case, you can use the monotone convergence theorem (instead of DCT) with $X_n := \sum_{j=1}^n1_{A_j}X$, since these obviously satisfy $0\le X_1\le X_2\le\dots$ and $X_n\nearrow 1_{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n}X$. The conclusion is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{A_n}X := \lim_{n\to\infty}\int X_n = \int_{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n}X.
$$
To recover the result when $X$ is not nonnegative, simply use linearity with the decomposition $X = X^+ - X^-$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment!